# Difference between Matrix Groups and Linear Groups?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I am attempting to understand the difference between linear groups and matrix groups. After consulting my primary textbook, Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra book edition 3, as well as the web, this is my understanding thus far:

According to Dummit and Foote, linear representations and matrix representations are defined as follows:

"Definition:

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$.

A linear representation of $G$ is any homomorphism from $G$ into $GL(V)$. The degree of the representation is the dimension of $V$.

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. A matrix representation of $G$ is any homomorphism from $G$ into $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$.

A linear or matrix representation is faithful if it is injective.

So, I think linear groups are groups that have a faithful representation in $GL(V)$, and matrix groups are groups that have a faithful representation in $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$?

Please let me know if this is correct, or if I am missing something! I am having a difficult time finding a comprehensive explanation of these terms (namely, the differences between all of these terms).

EDIT: Also, I am wondering if there is a difference between groups that "begin" as matrix groups such as $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ or $SL_n(\mathbb{F})$, compared to groups that arise in a different fashion, such as $D_{2n}$ or $Q_8$, but have a faithful representation as matrix group?

Comment: Seems right to me, although the difference is not very significant; the two notions are equivalent after choosing a basis.

Comment: Both of these terms are slightly ambiguous; there are issues like whether we just want to work over a field, or whether we just want to consider finite-dimensional vector spaces. If $V$ is always taken to be finite-dimensional then the two classes of groups are the same.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for these clarifying words- just making sure I won't get into trouble somewhere down the road if I operate off of these definitions.